# Can I fix/use the Swapcard code example? It seems it doesn't work for me

Tags: reactjs

I setup a basic app using `npx create-react-app swapcard`.
Then I install the SDK using `npm install @swapcard/react-sdk` like noted in https://developer.swapcard.com/react-sdk/about-the-react-sdk.

Then I run `npm start`.

Then I try to even just import the event details line `import { ExhibitorEventDetails } from "@swapcard/react-sdk/lib/exhibitor/event-details";` from https://developer.swapcard.com/react-sdk/pages/exhibitor-event-details and it instantly gives me 20 errors.

Is the package bad? Can I fix it?

I am also getting a lot of npm warnings when running `npm i`.

Anyway the errors I get being:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql-tag/lib/index.js 62:17-22
export 'parse' (imported as 'parse') was not found in 'graphql' (module has no exports)
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 15:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/kevinernst/Documents/Projects/swapcard/node_modules/mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 25:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './version' in '/Users/kevinernst/Documents/Projects/swapcard/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'version.mjs'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './version' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

and much more after that.

It's easy to recreate by doing the few steps I did.

Tried to swap versions, remove 'react' from package.json since @swapcard/react-sdk already includes them. Tried in another app, tried standalone (like the example now).

Tried to install some of the things in the errors. Didn't put a dent in it.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It gives some hints

Comment: I can fix the polyfill error, just not any of the others. Since I don't include graphql myself.

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 53:0-65:205
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './language' in '/Users/kevinernst/Documents/Projects/swapcard/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'index.mjs'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './language' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"')

Comment: I don't know how I would make it a type module since I only use the import '...' like the docs say